# data handling in matlab gui - reading from file and textbox and pass to function

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I was tasked today (by my professor, thank you sir) to create a GUI in Matlab for a script I wrote. The script is used to set a few values (read from text file, manipulate, assign to variable) and then calls three functions to actually calculate something and print the plot to a file - pretty straight forward I guess.

I now have to make all the input-sections in a gui, the output I guess can stay as it is (calculation is lengthy so there is nothing to show maybe a progress bar for the impatient).

I am pretty much confused by all the handles, hObject and so on, I hope someone can guide me.

Here is what I did so far:

The object I simulate has several layers, these have 2 properties, the thickness, and the an optical function. I type in the thickness in a "Edit Text" and load the file with a pushbutton.

```
    % --- Executes on button press in load_cathode.
function load_cathode_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
[filename, pathname] = uigetfile('*.txt');
loaddata = fullfile(pathname,filename);
cathode_nk=load(loaddata); handles.cathode = [cathode_nk(:,1)'; cathode_nk(:,2)'.^2-cathode_nk(:,3)'.^2+2*i*cathode_nk(:,2)'.*cathode_nk(:,3)'];
%assignin('base','cathode',cathode_nk)
```

for the EditText

```
function d_cathode_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
handles.d_cathode=str2double(get(hObject,'String'));
```

I will do this several times and end up with several handles.*name* things and handles.d_*names*.

How do i proceed in using this data to actually call the function part of my software, and how do I get the EditText when i push the final button. To my understanding the handles struct is shared over all the GUI, right?

Thanks for anyone who has read so far and special thanks if someone can help me!

Chris

Comment: Like you said the handles structure is shared throughout the gui. If you append something to handles as you did with d_cathod_Callback, and then you trigger another callback (maybe through a button press) you'll be able to access the data you stored in handles by accessing handles.d_cathode. hObject is a the handle to the object executing the callback. This can be useful sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this template:

```
function d_cathode_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles);
%in main file make empty struct handles= guihandles(gcf); guidata(gcf, handles);
%and load struct in function
handles = guidata(hObject);
%body ...
handles.d_cathode=str2double(get(hObject,'String'));
%save changes
guidata(hObject, handles);
%now use the same way to access to handles.d_cathode in other function
```

Comment: If hObject is not a figure handle, then the object's parent figure is used.

Comment: Thank you so much! Stackoverflow is the best place to get help!